# Any way to make a class conform a generic protocol in Swift?

Tags: swift, module

What I'm going to do is modularizing our app in Swift. Modules communicate with each other via a protocol(called service). Here is my assumption:

```
protocol Service {
    var provider: Any? { get }
}

struct ServiceProvider<T> {
    static func provider() -> Any? {

        // compile error here, any workaround?
        struct Imp: T {}
        return Imp.provider
    }
}

/********** Shopping Trolly Module ************/

public protocol ShoppingTrollyService {}

// provide
extension ShoppingTrollyService {
    var provider: Any? {
        return ShoppingTrollyServiceProvider()
    }
}

//this class can not be accessed from other module directly
class ShoppingTrollyServiceProvider: ShoppingTrollyService {}
```

Then in other module:

```
let x = ServiceProvider<ShoppingTrollyService>.provider()
// then call function provided by ShoppingTrollyService
```

But I'm stuck at creating a concrete instance conforming some protocol(as error shown above). Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error is because it is unknown what type `T` is, therefore it is unknown that it has a member `provider()`. You can tell the compiler that `T` must be a `Service` by constraining it's type.

```
struct ServiceProvider<T:Service> { // Notice the constraint on T
    static func provider() -> Any? {

        struct Imp: T {}
        return Imp.provider // We can call this because we know T must conform to Service
    }
}
```